# Overloading << and >> in C++ to perform decimal shifts

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload the << and >> operators to perform decimal shifts, but I'm not seeing how to do that. For example, I'll have a member function of a class myclass

```
myclass myclass::operator<<(myclass ob2)
{
    //Code in here for overloading <<
    //In the object, there is a float value to perform the shift on
}
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: What should happen to the `float` value when you shift it?

Comment: In this context, what does "decimal shifts" mean?

Comment: I don’t understand where your problem lies.

Comment: I think he wants to shift the decimal point in float

Comment: Did you mean `myclass::operator <<(int digits)` and then shift the decimal point by `digits` digits, i.e. multiplying with `pow(10, digits)`?

Comment: The float value has to be changed. For example, I'm wanting to make 13.34 << 1 change the float value of 13.34 to 133.4, and leaving the << unchanged.

Comment: "leaving the << unchanged" - what do you mean by that? What's the "<<" in this context - the input value 1?

Comment: Please don't do this using operator overloading, use functions instead. Readers of your code five years down the road will not be able to guess what `<<` means for your class.

Comment: Is the question "how do I overload `operator <<` and `>>` to do something I specify", or is it "how do I write code to perform a decimal shift? Also, http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably a "decimal shift" means shifting the decimal point left (right, for `operator>>`) by a specified number of digits.

In this case, you probably want the parameter to be an unsigned int:

```
myclass &myclass::operator<<(unsigned digits) { 
     value *= pow(10, digits);
     return *this;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us why it has to be unsigned?

Comment: @leemes - it doesn't have to, but if it isn't you have to decide what a negative shift should do.

Comment: A mutating `<<` operator looks *very* unexpected!

Comment: @KerrekSB: It is, but according to his comments ("the float value has to be changed"), it seems to be what he wants.

Answer (score 4):

In general I'd suggest that you leave `<<` non-mutating, and use `<<=` to change values in-place.

Also, unless impossible to set/get the `float`/`double` member of your class, there's no need to make the operators class members.

```
struct myclass {
    double value;
};

// mutate in-place: take the instance by non-const reference,
// and return a reference to the same instance
myclass& operator<<=(myclass &self, unsigned places) {
    self.value *= std::pow(10, places);
    return self;
}

myclass& operator>>=(myclass &self, unsigned places) {
    self.value /= std::pow(10, places);
    return self;
}

// create a new instance and return it by value
myclass operator<<(myclass const &original, unsigned places) {
    myclass temp(original);
    temp <<= places;
    return temp;
}

myclass operator>>(myclass const &original, unsigned places) {
    myclass temp(original);
    temp >>= places;
    return temp;
}
```

And use like:

```
int main() {
    myclass a = {0.1};
    std::cout << "a := " << a.value << '\n';

    myclass b = a << 1;
    std::cout << "b = (a << 1) := " << b.value << '\n';

    b >>= 1;
    std::cout << "b >>= 1 := " << b.value << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this:

```
myclass myclass::operator<<(int digits) const { 
    myclass result;
    result.value = this->value * pow(10, digits);
    return result;
}
myclass myclass::operator>>(int digits) const { 
    myclass result;
    result.value = this->value * pow(0.1, digits);
    return result;
}
```

This makes sure that `this` is unchanged, so you have to write

```
number = number << 3;
```

to modify a number, so when writing

```
otherNumber = number << 3;
```

this leaves `number` unchanged, as requested in your comments on the question. The `const` in the signature tells the code which uses this operator that the left hand operand stays unchanged.

Typically, you have also operators which operate directly on a target object, these are the operators having also the `=` in them. Technically, they are unrelated to their corresponding non-assigning operators, so you should define them accordingly for consistency:

```
myclass & myclass::operator<<=(int digits) {
    this->value *= pow(10, digits);
    return *this;
}
myclass & myclass::operator>>=(int digits) {
    this->value *= pow(0.1, digits);
    return *this;
}
```